# How to join on integer "binary" composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary

I have a table with a column containing an integer which when converted to binary represents a permutation of interests. For example:

```
John, Smith, 6
David, Jones, 512
Mark, Clark, 2
```

Let's say our `Interests` table looks something like:

```
1, TV
2, Music
4, Current Affairs
...
512, Sport
```

I would want my output to be:

```
John, Smith, Music
John, Smith, Current Affairs
David, Jones, Sport
Mark, Clark, Music
```

There are currently 15 interests in the table, leaving 2^15 possible permutations (I think).

The only thing I can think of at the moment is using a loop/cursor of some sort to build a mapping table with every permutation which I can then join to.

Is there another way? (I wonder if I can just put each interest in the table and use a function in the join criteria to see if the bit is set for that interest?)

Or could you assist with the SQL to build the mapping table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT S.Name, S.Surname, I.Name
FROM SomeTable S
JOIN Interests I
  ON I.ID & S.InterestCombinedID > 0
```

`&` is a [bitwise AND operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

As example,

```
2 & 6 = 10b  & 110b = 10b  = 2 > 0  and
4 & 6 = 100b & 110b = 100b = 4 > 0
```

Thus `John Smith` (6) will get matched up with `Music` (2) and `Current Affairs` (4).

Unfortunately this won't allow for indices (as far as I know). To allow for indices, you may have to resort to a join on the `Interest` table for each bit that is set (either using a loop or a CTE) (or changing your table structure). Obviously this would be a lot more complex, and, since there are currently only 15 interests, the difference in complexity should be hardly noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive CTE to calculate all your combinations of interesets and just join on it:

```
WITH RCTE_Interests AS 
(
    SELECT  id, CAST(name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) interests FROM dbo.Interests i
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT r.id + i.id, r.interests + ',' + i.name FROM RCTE_Interests r
    INNER JOIN dbo.Interests i ON i.ID > r.ID
)
SELECT t.name, t.lastname, r.interests 
FROM RCTE_Interests r
INNER JOIN Table1 t ON r.id = t.id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0b17/1)**

**EDIT:** After additional info from comment, I see query is not really returning the exactly expected answer. Here is additional tweak to get records for multiple records for multi-interest IDs.

Simple - just join `RCTE_Interests` back to `Interests` table:

```
WITH RCTE_Interests AS 
(
    SELECT  id, CAST(name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) interests FROM dbo.Interests i
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT r.id + i.id, r.interests + ',' + i.name FROM RCTE_Interests r
    INNER JOIN dbo.Interests i ON i.ID > r.ID
)
SELECT r.ID, i.Name AS interests 
FROM RCTE_Interests r
INNER JOIN dbo.Interests i ON r.interests LIKE '%' + i.name + '%'
ORDER BY r.ID
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO - multiple rows per interest](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0b17/4)**

**[SQLFiddle DEMO - multiple rows results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0b17/2)**

Comment: thanks nenad- if i do decide from a performance perspective i need to go down this route. two small things though- 1. i wouldn't build the table on the fly (i can tweak to take care of that). 2. your mapping table comma delimites the interests- i want to actually return multiple records as per my example. could you tweak it to do that please?

Comment: @LeeTickett Yeah - sure, I'll update the answer. Also was going to suggest to just use query to fill a table and run it only if something changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross join between both the tables and select only the columns you need.

```
Select * from TableA A Cross JOIN TableB B
```